# Stop loop once if value is met one time

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, logic, modulus

I have a for loop checking the result of value % i. Inside, there is an if statement checking if value % i = 0. If it does equal zero, it sets boolean isDivisible to true. If it returns a nonzero it sets isDivisible to false. The issue is that, for example, if the value is 12, *some* attempts will return 0 while some will be nonzero, so isDivisible is constantly changing inaccurately. I want the loop to end once value % i = 0. Is such a thing possible?

```
for (int i=2; i < value; i++){
            if (value % i == 0){
                isDivisible = true;
            }
            else{
                isDivisible = false;
            }
        }
        if (isDivisible = true){
                System.out.println(value + " is prime");
            }
```

Comment: So you want to use `break;` to break out of the loop?

Comment: I can't see you `break`ing anywhere in your code...

Comment: isDivisible = true;
break;

Comment: use break or alternatively a while loop might better suit the needs of a boolean check, while (value % i !== 0) i++;

Comment: `if (isDivisible = true){` first assigns `true` to `isDivisible` then that value is used by `if`. You may want to use `==true`, or simply skip `=true` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
isDivisible = false;
for (int i=2; i < value; i++){
    if (value % i == 0){
        isDivisible = true;
        System.out.println(value + " is divisible");
        break;//loop break when divisible
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i=2; i < value; i++){
            if (value % i == 0){
                isDivisible = true;
                break;
            }
            else{
                isDivisible = false;
            }
        }
        if (isDivisible = true){
                System.out.println(value + " is prime");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use break;

break; stops the current exectuion of a loop and exits it.

```
for (int i=2; i < value; i++){
        if (value % i == 0){
            isDivisible = true;
            break;
        }
        else{
            isDivisible = false;
        }
    }
```

And as you see here, you don't need that second if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Using `break` of course is the standard way. Another option would be:

```
isDivisible = false;
for (int i=2; i < value && !isDivisible; i++){
    if (value % i == 0){
        isDivisible = true;
    }
}
```

Also, you only need to iterate up to `Math.sqrt(value)`.